# isAuthenticated is always false while using passport with sequelize

Tags: node.js, passport.js, sequelize.js

While trying to get isAuthenticated to work as a middleware check, I cant seem to get this to be true.I have logged the results and everytime no matter what I have tried it always ends up being false. I would like to get some help on why this might be happening. Thank you all in advance to anyone who offers to help me with this. The db i am using is mysql if it helps any.

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {

 if (req.isAuthenticated()){
     console.log('user logged in', req.user);
     return next();
 }else{
    console.log('user not logged in');
    res.redirect('/login');
}

}
```

this is my route

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
    successRedirect : '/admin', 
    failureRedirect : '/login', 
    failureFlash : true 
}));
```

And my passport.js local stratagy

```
passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField : 'username',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true 
},
function(req, username, password, done) {
    models.User.find({ where:{'username' :username }}).then(function(user) {
        passwd = user ? user.password : ''
        if (!user)
            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.')); 

        if (!models.User.validPassword(password, passwd))
            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.')); 

        return done(null, user);
    });
}));
```

And i set up my server.js like this

```
 app.use(morgan('dev')); // log every request to the console
 app.use(cookieParser()); // read cookies (needed for auth)
 app.use(bodyParser.json()); // get information from html forms
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
 app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); 

 app.use(session({
    secret: 'tengence' ,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
 })); // session secret
 require('./config/passport')(passport);
 app.use(passport.initialize());
 app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
 app.use(flash()); 

 require('./app/routes.js')(app, passport);

 app.listen(port);
 console.log('Server started at ' + port);
```

Answer (score 1):

I feel like an idiot as i forgot to add this little method that happens to call login. Its been a long day of coding and my eyes just needed rest i guess.

```
 ///Very important to not to forget to do below!!
        req.login(user, function(err){
            if (err) {
                return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Something went wrong.' + err));
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please mark this answer as the accepted answer because then it won't show up as an unanswered question. :)

Comment: I cant until tomorrow according to stack overflow